# Use DWC3 module to put USB-C port in Host mode

Tags: usb, bios, usb-c

This is a repost of my question originally posted on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange site (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638148/change-usb-c-port-from-usb-device-to-usb-host-and-vice-versa-to-emulate-a-mass-s) as I believe this question belongs more on AskUbuntu site.

I have a project which consists into using a device running Ubuntu server which will be connected to a windows computer through a USB-C/USB-A cable. The USB-C would be connected the Ubuntu device and the USB-A to the windows computer. The PC will then send data through this cable to the Ubuntu emulated mass storage.

What changes do I have to make to the BIOS, ACPI or else to make this possible?

`sudo lspci -nn -d ::0c03 -v` provides me this output:

```
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        DeviceName: Onboard - Other
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:7270]
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
        Memory at df530000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d30] (rev 21) (prog-if fe [USB Device])
        DeviceName: Onboard - Other
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at df000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
        Memory at df54f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: dwc3-pci
        Kernel modules: dwc3_pci
```

EDIT 2:

This is my ACPI configuration:

```
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000851cb000-0x00000000851cbfff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000008c6ea000-0x000000008ca93fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.013210] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.013214] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F05B0 000024 (v02 ALASKA)
[    0.013218] ACPI: XSDT 0x000000008C6EA0B0 0000DC (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.013224] ACPI: FACP 0x000000008C713958 000114 (v06 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.013230] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000008C6EA220 029734 (v02 ALASKA A M I    01072009 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013233] ACPI: FACS 0x000000008CA93F00 000040
[    0.013236] ACPI: APIC 0x000000008C713A70 000084 (v03 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.013239] ACPI: FPDT 0x000000008C713AF8 000044 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.013242] ACPI: FIDT 0x000000008C713B40 00009C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.013246] ACPI: MCFG 0x000000008C713BE0 00003C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 MSFT 00000097)
[    0.013249] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C713C20 000359 (v01 SataRe SataTabl 00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013252] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C713F80 003165 (v02 SaSsdt SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013256] ACPI: HPET 0x000000008C7170E8 000038 (v01 INTEL  KBL-ULT  00000001 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.013259] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C717120 0011AA (v02 INTEL  Ther_Rvp 00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013262] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C7182D0 0009B3 (v02 INTEL  xh_rvp07 00000000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013265] ACPI: UEFI 0x000000008C718C88 000048 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000002      01000013)
[    0.013269] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C718CD0 0017AE (v02 CpuRef CpuSsdt  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013272] ACPI: LPIT 0x000000008C71A480 000094 (v01 INTEL  KBL-ULT  00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.013275] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C71A518 000141 (v02 INTEL  HdaDsp   00000000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013278] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C71A660 00029F (v02 INTEL  sensrhub 00000000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013282] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C71A900 003002 (v02 INTEL  PtidDevc 00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013285] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C71D908 000517 (v02 INTEL  TbtTypeC 00000000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013288] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008C71DE20 0002E9 (v02 INTEL  Wwan     00000001 INTL 20160422)
[    0.013291] ACPI: DBGP 0x000000008C71E110 000034 (v01 INTEL           00000002 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.013294] ACPI: DBG2 0x000000008C71E148 000054 (v00 INTEL           00000002 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.013297] ACPI: DMAR 0x000000008C71E1A0 0000B0 (v01 INTEL  EDK2     00000001 INTL 00000001)
[    0.013300] ACPI: ASF! 0x000000008C71E250 0000A0 (v32 INTEL   HCG     00000001 TFSM 000F4240)
[    0.013304] ACPI: WSMT 0x000000008C71E2F0 000028 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.013312] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.046794] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x1808
[    0.046796] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.046803] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.046804] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.046805] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.046806] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x04] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.046840] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.046841] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.046843] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.046844] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.046846] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.046848] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.112942] ACPI: Core revision 20190816
[    0.145825] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x851cb000-0x851cbfff] (4096 bytes)
[    0.145825] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x8c6ea000-0x8ca93fff] (3842048 bytes)
[    0.145825] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.145825] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.149423] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.149425] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.149426] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.149428] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.149431] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.149433] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.149435] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.202623] ACPI: 11 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.211141] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.211150] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F1A65816800 00060F (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.213026] ACPI: \_PR_.PR00: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked
[    0.214941] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.214948] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F1A64CAEC00 0003FF (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20160422)
[    0.216719] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.216725] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F1A64C78480 0000BA (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Hwp  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.218405] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.218411] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F1A64EAC800 000628 (v02 PmRef  HwpLvt   00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.220598] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.220607] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F1A6532B000 000D14 (v02 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.223342] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.223349] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F1A64CAD400 000317 (v02 PmRef  ApHwp    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.225173] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.225180] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F1A64CAF800 00030A (v02 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.230370] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.230422] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.230425] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.230476] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.231867] ACPI: Enabled 6 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
[    0.241288] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.263566] ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
[    0.263696] ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
[    0.263828] ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
[    0.263951] ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
[    0.264074] ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
[    0.265863] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-fe])
[    0.277730] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.277808] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
[    0.277882] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.277956] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.278030] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.278103] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.278176] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.278250] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.279095] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.279095] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.321967] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.322408] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.322461] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 PNP030b (active)
[    0.322520] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f03 PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.322736] system 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.322862] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.322912] system 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT3f0d PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.323266] system 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.323337] system 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.323739] system 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.325460] system 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.326686] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 10 devices
[    0.716581] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    0.718428] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.720134] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.723097] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
[    0.724786] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (30 C)
[    7.658677] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638148/change-usb-c-port-from-usb-device-to-usb-host-and-vice-versa-to-emulate-a-mass-s